# React Query useQuery not returning async API calls NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-query

I am trying to return an array of data that returns the firebase data that I fetched and the API call to return data. I already have two `useQuery` hooks and the one that only returns the firebase documents works fine. On my second `useQuery` hook, it doesn't return the price when I render the data, but the function is being called and it `console.logs` all the correct prices. I tried a similar version transferring the code to `onSettled`, but that returns a similar issue. I created two versions of the second `useQuery` hook, one with `Promise.all`, and another without promises completely. They both return nothing.

No Promise

```
  const fetchListDocs = async () => {
    try {
      const queryCollection = query(collection(db, loc));
      const snapshot = await getDocs(queryCollection);
    //   let arr = [];
      let retArr = []
      let newRetMap = new Map();
      snapshot.forEach(async (doc) => {
        const docTicker = doc.data().stockTicker
        // console.log(doc.data())
        // arr.push(doc.data());
        if (newRetMap.has(docTicker)) {
            //averaging price code here
        } else {
            const newPrice = await getStockPrice(docTicker).then((result) => result);
            const currentPrice = parseFloat(newPrice.toFixed(2));
            newRetMap.set(docTicker, currentPrice)
            retArr.push(currentPrice)
        }
      });
      console.log(retArr)
    //   newRetMap.entries((value) => {
    //     retArr.push(value)
    //   })

      return retArr;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const { data: listDocs, status } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["firestoreListDocuments", db],
    queryFn: () => fetchListDocs(),
    onSettled: (dataCollection) => {

        return dataCollection

    }
  });
```

With Promise

```
const fetchListDocs = async () => {
    try {
      const queryCollection = query(collection(db, loc));
      const snapshot = await getDocs(queryCollection);
    //   let arr = [];
      let retArr = []
      let newRetMap = new Map();
      snapshot.forEach(async (doc) => {
        const docTicker = doc.data().stockTicker
        // console.log(doc.data())
        // arr.push(doc.data());
        if (newRetMap.has(docTicker)) {
            //averaging price code here
        } else {
            let newPrice = await getStockPrice(docTicker).then((result) => result);
            newPrice = Promise.resolve(newPrice)
            console.log(newPrice)
            const currentPrice = parseFloat(newPrice);
            
            newRetMap.set(docTicker, currentPrice)
            retArr.push(currentPrice)
        }
      });
      console.log(retArr)
    //   newRetMap.entries((value) => {
    //     retArr.push(value)
    //   })

      return Promise.all(retArr);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

I would appreciate any and all help. Please let me know if there are any questions.

Comment: I believe you need to put states and useEffects and put the changing inside useEffect so that your component re-renders when the data is fetched.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Promise API call not rendering in time NextJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75053009/promise-api-call-not-rendering-in-time-nextjs)

Comment: @TomasVancoillie I wrote that post because I couldn't find a solution to my problem. I am still a little confused. I have a way to get the individual prices but its difficult to destructure