# Promise API call not rendering in time NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-query

I am making calls to an API function that I set up and that works all the time. I have used the same backend API calling on another project and in the same project but on the same page and it works fine. In this instance, however, I believe it is due to my lack of understanding of `Promise` statements that I am not able to solve this. When I run the code, everything runs normally. The `fetcher` statement works and returns a map of the different stocks in the database. For now, that is all I want. The console prints out the prices of the stocks, but it does not save it to state, which is what I am doing `onSuccess`.

```
const fetchListDocs = async () => {
    try {
      const queryCollection = query(collection(db, loc));
      const snapshot = await getDocs(queryCollection);
      //   let arr = [];
      let retArr = [];
      let newRetMap = new Map();
      snapshot.forEach(async (doc) => {
        const docTicker = doc.data().stockTicker;
        // console.log(doc.data())
        // arr.push(doc.data());
        if (newRetMap.has(docTicker)) {
          //averaging price code here
          let data = newRetMap.get(docTicker);
          const type = doc.data().type;
          let newShares = parseFloat(data.shares);
          let newPrice = parseFloat(data.price);
          console.log(newPrice);
          console.log(newShares);

          const oldAmount = newShares * newPrice;
          console.log(oldAmount);
          if (type === "buy") {
            newShares = newShares + parseFloat(doc.data().shares);
            newPrice = (oldAmount + parseFloat(doc.data().price)) / newShares;
          } else {
            newShares = newShares - parseFloat(doc.data().shares);
            newPrice = (oldAmount - parseFloat(doc.data().price)) / newShares;
          }

          console.log(newPrice);
          console.log(newShares);

          const newData = {
            price: newPrice,
            shares: newShares,
            stockTicker: docTicker,
            // id: doc.id
          };
          newRetMap.set(docTicker, newData);

          console.log(newData);
        } else {
          newRetMap.set(docTicker, doc.data());
        }
      });

      console.log(retArr);

      newRetMap.forEach(async (value, key) => {
        const newPrice = await getStockPrice(key).then((result) => result);
        const currentPrice = parseFloat(newPrice.toFixed(2));
        const pl = (
          parseFloat(value.shares) *
          (currentPrice - parseFloat(value.price))
        ).toFixed(2);
        const fixedPrice = value.price.toFixed(2);
        const totalEq = (parseFloat(value.shares) * currentPrice).toFixed(2);
        const insertAvg = {
          ticker: key,
          shares: value.shares,
          averagePrice: fixedPrice,
          currentPrice,
          profitLoss: pl,
          dividendYield: "Coming Soon",
        };
        retArr.push(insertAvg);
      });

      setListDocuments(retArr);

      return retArr;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

const { data: listDocs, status } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["firestoreListDocuments", db],
    queryFn: () => fetchListDocs(),
    onSettled: async (dataCollection) => {
      console.log(dataCollection);

      return dataCollection;
    },
  });


  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(listDocs)
    setListDocuments(listDocs);
  },[listDocuments])
```

I am using React Query for the query client. It is running on NextJs 12. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I added the useEffect statement to see if anything would change during rerendering. It console. Logs the correct information, but it still doesn't show up.

Comment: So what's going on here, what works, what doesn't? `listDocs` is not showing any data? Why do you set a separate state with `setListDocuments` when you can use `listDocs` from the returned useQuery hook?

Comment: listDocs and listDocuments eventually work, they console log arrays of data. I rendered stringified versions of both arrays but they both render empty. Everything works when I take out the getStockPrice implementation. I believe it is because it is a promise. @TomasVancoillie

Answer (score 0):

Change it to a for loop.

```
for (const [key, value] of newRetMap) {
  const newPrice = await getStockPrice(key).then((result) => result);
}
```